# while executing plsql block returns query result when data present in the DB.When data is not found the query result returns nothing from exception

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, plsql

```
if [ $returncode -eq 0 ]

then

 query_msg=`$ISQL -S $USERNAME/$PASSWD@$SERVICENAME <<EOJ

        set serveroutput on;

        set heading off;

        set feedback off;

        set linesize 150;

declare

        out_value varchar2(32767);
BEGIN

for c in (SELECT MESSAGE into out_value FROM RED.ERROR_LOG 

  WHERE PROC = 'colour' 

    AND to_char(to_date(DT,'DD-MON-YY')) = to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')))

    loop

    out_value :=c.MESSAGE;

    dbms_output.put_line(out_value);

end loop;

    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

            dbms_output.put_line('Nothing found');

END;

/
```

when no data is found the exception block is not returning the nothing found statement. could some correct me where im going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The exception NO_DATA_FOUND is not raised at the end of a cursor loop: when end of data is reached, the code just exits the loop without raising any exception. This also true even if the SELECT statement does not return any row.

In general NO_DATA_FOUND is raised when running a SELECT statement that does not return any row but not if the SELECT is a cursor loop SELECT statement.

Comment: so what shud be my code . ? do i need to close loop after the exception ? it throws error if i do ? How to handle when no data found.

Comment: You can add a counter to count the number of rows found in the loop. After the end of the loop you can check if the counter is equal to 0 and in this case add for example the instruction `raise no_data_found;` to create an exception if needed.